# Алгоритм быcтрого вычисления длины строки

Tags: алгоритм, c++

Раскопал в интернете следующий код для вычисления длинны строки (оптимизированный под большие строки)

```
    #define STDCALL __stdcall
const size_t STDCALL strlen4( const char * str )
{
    const char* p = str;
    while ((DWORD_PTR)p & 3)
    {
        if (!*p)
        {
            return p - str;
        }
        ++p;
    }
    DWORD v = *(DWORD*)p;
    while(!(((~v) ^ (v + 0x7efefeff)) & 0x81010100))
    {
        p += 4;
        v = *(DWORD*)p;
    }
    const size_t l = p - str;
    if (v & 0xff)
    {
        if (v & 0xff00)
        {
            if (v & 0xff0000)
            {
                return l + 3;
            }
            return l + 2;
        }
        return l + 1;
    }
    return l;
}
```

И я никак не могу понять, что происходит вот в этом цикле этой функции и для чего он нужен:

```
while ((DWORD_PTR)p & 3)
    {
        if (!*p)
        {
            return p - str;
        }
        ++p;
    }
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.... Пробовал эксперементировать с разными значениями строки, и пока что мне удавалось зайти  в этот цикл только в тех случаях, когда входная строка была пустой, т.е. состояла только из '0', но если это только для пустых строк, то зачем тогда цикл делать... Вообщем, помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться...

Answer (score 2):

Указатель p указывает на текущий символ строки. Как известно, строка должна оканчиваться символом 0 (нуль-терминатор). В условии указатель разадресуется, и если он указывает на нуль-терминатор, то условие становится истинным (!0 == true), значит, мы дошли до конца строки и длина строки будет равна разности текущего адреса и адреса начала строки. В противном случае мы увеличиваем на 1 p (переходим на следующий символ) и повторяем всё сначала.

Comment: в условие выход в цикл написано (DWORD_PTR)p & 3 , я так понял что там указатель на сhar приводится к типу указатель на беззнаковый длинный int, а потом производится опперация & 3 . Я только не понимаю для чего это делается и в каких случаях этот цикл будет выполнятся...

Comment: Строка (DWORD_PTR)p & 3 - это хитро замаскированное определение остатка от деления p на 4. & - побитовое И, при применении p & 3 происходит взятие последних двух битов числа p, что даёт остаток от деления p на 4. Такое взятие остатка быстрее обычного %, поэтому и используется в быстром алгоритме.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо. Но я до сих пор не понимаю зачем нужно считать остаток от деленеия на 4 от адреса содержачегося в (DWORD_PTR)p ? Какой в этом смысл?
Почему нельзя при определении длянны строки только вторым циклом while(!(((~v) ^ (v + 0x7efefeff)) & 0x81010100)){ и т.д.}
Зачем нужен цикл  while ((DWORD_PTR)p & 3) ?

Comment: Эта хохма для процессоров, где 32-битные целые должны быть выравнены на границы 4х байт. И если строка начинается не с этой границы, то первые байты (до границы) надо проверить как-нибудь иначе (здесь -- в лоб, напрямую), поскольку попытка выбрать по этому адресу целое вызовет ошибку выравнивания. А далее операции идут уже над четырёхбайтными целыми, и с захватом байт в последней четвёрке вне строки. Но переносимость у функции ограничена: порядок байт фиксирован -- мл.байт впереди, т.е. имеет меньший адрес, а это не везде так.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо. А в каких случаях может так получится, что строка начинётся не с этой границы ?

Comment: Масса вариантов. Если целые (как в s/360 и потомках, но пример неудачен из-за порядка байт) размещаются на границе 4х-байтного слова (короткие -- полуслова), а строки -- на границе байта, то при размещении строк такие случаи возможны. Или вы берете часть строки с отступом 1-3 байта от начала. Или...

Comment: Возможен ещё вариант, хотя тут я просто неграмотен -- разное время операции сложения при выравнивании числа на границу 4б (в 386/486)

Answer (score 0):

В перовом цикле происходит выравнивание адреса `p` на 4 байта. В нем автор проверяет не равен ли один из не выравненных байтов `\0`, то есть не кончается ли на нем строка. Выравнивание на 4 байта здесь делается потому, что далее выполняется чтение и итерация сразу по 4 байта, а вот это сложное условие `while(!(((~v) ^ (v + 0x7efefeff)) & 0x81010100))` проверяет не содержится ли в одном из 4 байтов значение `\0` то есть конец строки. Эта проверка требует чтобы прочитанные 4 байта заносились в переменную типа `DWORD` - целое безнаковое число. На многих процессорных архитектурах для такого чтения требуется чтобы адрес был выравнен на размер целочисленного типа то есть на те самые 4 байта. Семейство x86 (условный "интел"), при невыравненном чтении автоматически выполняет два выравненых чтения и потом склеивание нужных байтиков в одно целое, происходит это минимум в три раза медленнее чем выравненное чтение. А есть архитектуры которые молча выравнивают в какую-либо строну указатель и читают хлам по не правильному адресу, бывает и так.

Таким образом, суть оптимизации состоит в том, что обход массива символов выполняется сразу по 4 байта. Выравнивание же нужно чтобы сделать такой обход правильно и быстро.